# Watch array changes in AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service object which exposes an array that I would like to watch for changes (within the service) and then call a method.

This is trivial inside a controller by watching changes to the array on it's $scope, but how can the same be accomplished in a service?
The service is shared in several controllers and I don't want to implement the logic in many places.

I have tried using Polymer's ArrayObserver, but it doesn't seem to work with Angular.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the watch on the `$rootScope`, i.e.:

```
.service("mySvc", function($rootScope,...) {
    var myArray = ...
    ...
    $rootScope.$watchCollection(
        function() {
            return myArray;
        },
        function(newval) {
            ...
        }
    );
```

However you have to be extra careful to unregister the watch when (if) it is no longer needed.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to do it without using rootScopet, these are transient models and I don't want references to rootScope stopping disposal. Manually destroying could be an option, but difficult to garauntee in this use case

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use `$watchCollection` to watch array changes

```
var arrayChangeListner = $rootScope.$watchCollection(function(){
});
```

Unregister the watch if it is no longer needed as @Nikos mentioned

$watch returns a deregistration function, To unregister call that function like this

```
arrayChangeListner();
```

For reference:

1. [Angular DOcs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)
2. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm

Hope it helps